# How to make a universal table with directories (dictionaries)?

Tags: php, laravel

I constantly meet this task.

I would like to find a one-stop solution.

I have some tables. They have a set of identical fields.

#### Table type_applications

```
id   name   title         
1    game   Games         
2    app    Application   
3    arcade Arcade
```

#### Table type_tasks

```
id   name      title          
1    create    Create App     
2    update    Update App     
3    publish   Publish App
```

#### Table status_applications

```
id   name       title         
1    created    Games         
2    moderation Moderated application
3    publish    Application published
```

There is a table to which these directories belong.

#### Table tasks

```
id   name         title           status_id  type_task_id type_application_id  
1    first_app    My First game   3          2            1
2    second_app   My Second game  2          3            2
3    third_app    My third game   1          1            3
```

#### Accordingly, there are 4 models.

The Task model has a relationship with the application type model, with the status model and with the task type model.

```
public function type_application()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TypeApplication::class);
}

public function type_task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TypeTask::class);
}

public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Status::class);
}
```

How to make a universal table with directories (type_applications, type_tasks, status_applications)?

I see a solution to make a table types.

#### Table types

```
id   name       title                  type         
1    game       Games                  type_application
2    app        Application            type_application
3    arcade     Arcade                 type_application
4    create     Create App             type_task
5    update     Update App             type_task
6    publish    Publish App            type_task
7    created    Created application    status
8    moderation Moderated application  status
9    publish    Application published  status
```

There will be a relationship with types in the task model.

```
public function type_application()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class)->whereType('type_application');
}

public function type_task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class)->whereType('type_task');
}

public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class)->whereType('status');
}
```

Can you offer more solutions to this task?

Maybe some design pattern is suitable for this task?

Comment: Hi. This question would probably fit better over at some forum that's more built towards discussions than SO. This is a FAQ for when you're having specific programming issues and if the structure you have works and you just want to know if there are alternatives, it's unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: This seems like a classic question to me, and most likely there are standard solutions that have been discussed a thousand times. I just could not google them. Most likely, my English is very poor, and so you think I'm trying to develop a discussion. Please forgive me for my English.

Comment: There is a special function that does exactly this called "polymorphic relationships" in laravel